# How to write code for Breadth-first search in C++

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

I have been trying to do a graph search for a problem from [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bfsshortreach). Lastly, I have come up with

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void bfs(list<int> adjacencyList[], int start, int countVertices) {
    // initialize distance[]
    int distance[countVertices];
    for(int i=0;i < countVertices; i++) {
        distance[i] = -1;
    }

    list<int>::iterator itr;
    int lev = 0;
    distance[start-1] = lev;          // distance for the start vertex is 0
                                      // using start -1 since distance is array which are 0-indexed

    list<int> VertexQueue;
    VertexQueue.push_back(start);

    while(!VertexQueue.empty()) {
        int neighbour = VertexQueue.front();
        itr = adjacencyList[neighbour].begin();

        while(itr != adjacencyList[neighbour].end()) {
            int vertexInd = (*itr) - 1;
            if(distance[vertexInd] == -1) {           // a distance of -1 implies that the vertex is unexplored
                distance[vertexInd] = (lev + 1) * 6;
                VertexQueue.push_back(*itr);
            }
            itr++;
        }
        VertexQueue.pop_front();
        lev++;
    }

    // print the result
    for(int k=0;k< countVertices;k++) {
        if (k==start-1) continue;     // skip the start node
        printf("%d ",distance[k]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int countVertices,countEdges,start,T,v1,v2;

    scanf("%d", &T);

    for(int i=0; i<T; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d", &countVertices,&countEdges);

        list<int> adjacencyList[countVertices];

        // input edges in graph
        for(int j=0; j<countEdges; j++) {
            scanf("%d%d",&v1,&v2);
            adjacencyList[v1].push_back(v2);
            adjacencyList[v2].push_back(v1);        // since the graph is undirected
        }

        scanf("%d",&start);

        bfs(adjacencyList, start, countVertices);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, this is resulting in 'Segmentation Fault' and I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.
Also, I have comes across segmentation fault a lot of times, but have no idea how to debug it. Would be great if someone can give me an idea of that.

Comment: Use a debugger and check the stack trace at the time of segfault.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d%d", &countVertices,&countEdges);
list<int> adjacencyList[countVertices];
```

Above code appears wrong. If your indices start with `1`, either make `adjacencyList` of size `countVertices + 1` or decrease `u` and `v` before putting them in the list.

You can also use a (an unordered) map mapping vertex to a list which will not segfault.

Also not that [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of standard C++, so avoid them even if your compiler support them as extension.